# Vuejs open a PDF file in a new tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My actual code do the PDF download, its working fine. But instead of download i would like to open the PDF file in a new tab. Can anyone help?

'''

```
<div class="table__buttons display-if">
    <template v-for="action in meta.actions">
      <a
        v-if="action === 'buttonDownload'"
        :key="action"
        :href="actions(action).to"
        :target="actions(action).target"
        :class="actions(action).class">
        <btn-table
          :tooltip="actions(action).tooltip"
          :icon-name="actions(action).iconName"
          type="button--table"
        />
      </a>

...

methods: {
    actions (action) {
      const { item, routes } = this.meta
      const actions = {
        // Actions params
        buttonDownload: {
          to: `${item['link']}`,
          target: '_blank',
          iconName: 'icon-download',
          tooltip: routes.buttonDownloadTooltip
        },
```

Comment: Have you tried using window.open() then passing the URL directly within a method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `target= '_blank'` in inline

Comment: Still doing just the download. Like it is now a new tab open and close in miliseconds and after the download is done.

Answer (score 0):

To view a PDF without downloading, try using `window.open('url/for/pdf', '_blank')`. This can be achieved by using a Vue click event handler rather than the default `<a>` tag behavior, like so:

```html
<a
    v-if="action === 'buttonDownload'"
    :key="action"
    :class="actions(action).class"
    @click.prevent="window.open(actions(action).to, '_blank')"
>
    ...
</a>
```